# "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel" Google Api response even if Heroku web application domain was verified

Tags: python, heroku, push-notification, google-api, watch

I have recently deployed python web application to Heroku platform that takes advantage of Google-calendar API. I was able to gain events list from calendar using *OAuth 2.0* credentials but web application domain verification isn't required in such cases in general. In opposite was with *push-notification* feature that requires either domain verification and HTTPS request sent to Google API to activate it.

**When I try to execute the HTTPS request using *watch* metod
with code:**

```
body={
            "id": "<specified_uuid_read_from_file>",
            "type": "web_hook",
            "address": "https://<heroku_application_id>.herokuapp.com"
      }
 events_result = service.events().watch(calendarId="primary", body=body).execute()
```

**I get this response**:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/watch?alt=json returned "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://<heroku_application_id>.herokuapp.com">
```

**I have already done:**

1. Verified domain *https://<heroku_application_id>.herokuapp.com* via Google Search Console by uploading html file.
2. Added this domain to Google Api "Domain verification" tab.

I would like to know what could be other possible resason than domain verification issues resulted from inappropriate Google authoriztion process and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
Eventually I was able to gain access by renewing Google API credentials. Everything works fine for now. Nevertheless I can't still explain what could be actual problem which caused this error.